# Search in controller or client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

with a rest call I get a list of items (name, location, …). The controller brings the items into the view and in the view the items will be showed. 
Now I like to build a full text search over items in the view (without reload) the page in the browser.

Is it better to build the search on client side (with jquery) or in the controller?
Is there a good example?

Regards
Stefan

Comment: If the returned result in the view are not supposed to change or with other worlds doesn’t need to be updated, it would be so logical to do what you wanna do  on client side.

Comment: The common practice is to do it on the server side as often you have to consider filtering, sorting, pagination and needless to mention that you can just rely on existing technoligies on the server side like RDBMS full text search or ElasticSearch.

Comment: Thanks, but I can do server side search without page reload?

Comment: "client side" can mean _fully_, or dependent on a server call (AJAX) without a "page reload". As commented above, the decision is based on whether or not the data changes, _not_ "server vs client side".